# How to transform a set of columns and rename them dynamically in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe ("df") that has ~50 columns that I would like to 
(1) multiply with the column "weight" (df$weight), and then 
(2) sum together by group (df$GEOID). 
I would like to add both a column with the product ("var.prod") and a column with the sum ("var.sum") to my dataframe.

I have figured out how to do this somewhat manually, but I wanted to know if there was a quicker  or more elegant solution. I am new to R so any feedback would be very helpful--thanks in advance!

This is what I have tried so far (I only list 6 variables in this example).

```
 vlist <- c("gini", "pov", "medinc", "pop", "inc", "pct.unemploy")
 for (v in vlist) {
   df[paste0(v,".prod")] <- df[paste0(v)]*df$weight
 }

 df <- df %>% 
   group_by(GEOID) %>% 
   mutate(gini.sum = sum(gini.prod),
          pov.sum = sum(pov.prod),
          medinc.sum = sum(medinc.prod),
          pop.sum = sum(pop.prod),
          inc.sum = sum(inc.prod),
          pct.unemploy.sum = sum(pct.unemploy.prod))
```

** Also, I'm working with a spatial dataframe so I can't use data.table functions. **

EDITED TO ADD:
I'm working with restricted data, so I can't share my data unfortunately. But this is an example of my data now:

```
 GEOID    gini   weight
 1        0.31   0.8
 1        0.45   0.2
 2        0.37   1
 3        0.42   1
```

And this is my intended output:

```
 GEOID    gini   weight   gini.prod   gini.sum
 1        0.31   0.8      0.248       0.338
 1        0.45   0.2      0.09        0.338
 2        0.37   1        0.37        0.37
 3        0.42   1        0.42        0.42
```

Comment: Please provide sample data (standard dataset or `dput(...)` or `data.frame(...)`) and your intended output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `mutate_at`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df <- df %>%
         group_by(GEOID) %>%
          mutate_at(vars(str_c(vlist, ".prod")), 
             list(sum =  ~ sum(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```

---

Or using `mutate` and `across`

```
df <- df %>%
        group_by(GEOID) %>%
        mutate(across(str_c(vlist, ".prod")), list(sum = sum)))
```

Comment: thanks--this is exactly what I was looking for. Do you know how I can create new column names (in my dataframe) for each of these sums?

Comment: @trinitysara updated the post.  YOu can wrap with `list` with a name and it will append suffix to the column name as a new column

Comment: Thanks for updating! I'm getting the following error "Error: expecting a one sided formula, a function, or a function name." Not sure why, but I will try playing around with the code.

Comment: @trinitysara sorry, it is because of the `na.rm= TRUE`, can you check now

Answer (score 0):

With `data.table`, you can do:

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

vlist <- c("gini", "pov", "medinc", "pop", "inc", "pct.unemploy")
df[, (lapply(.SD, sum)), by = "GEOID", .SDcols = paste0(vlist, ".prod")]
```

And if you want specific names:

```r
setnames(df, old = c("GEOID", paste0("V", 1:length(vlist)),
             new = c("GEOID", paste0(vlist, ".sum"))
)
```